# Google calendar API limits clarification

Tags: google-api, service-accounts, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

We are using service accounts to impersonate our calendar service support email inside our G-suite account and use that account to organize calendar events via the API synchronous with the meetings created inside our application for our customer users who will be added as attendee users (guests) to the calendar event. We came across this https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en. The limits mentioned in this document especially for the external invitations are very vague and is not clear.

It says the maximum number of external guest we can invite is from 100-300. do these limits app;y for service accounts? Are these limits enforced per event? What is the lower limit and what is the timeframe for which these limits will apply?

appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In order to prevent spamming, Google Calendar limits the number of invitations a user can send to external guests. This limit varies depending on the action, and is usually between 100-300 guests.

This is probably going to effect any user, normal or API usage.  This is to prevent spamming so personally i think it would be more of an issue for someone using the API so of course it would effect with service accounts as well.  Its an API limitation independent of the authentication method you are using.

Comment: So does the limit apply per event, per hour or per day?

Comment: my guess would be per event.  And for a single send. So if you are inviting 200 people i would do it in batches of 100 or something.  I would test it if i was you i dont have the power to test that i dont have 100+ emails i can invite to dummy events.